# How to set a solid color wallpaper?

Tags: wallpaper

My android comes with 3 different solid wallpapers. I have found more in the market but its paid. How to get a black wallpaper for free?

Comment: I used "Pitch Black Wallpaper" and I got just that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecdrop.pitchblackwallpaper&hl=en_US&gl=US

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you not make your own?

Open up paint or photoshop of some sort and fill an area black. Save the image as a png and then place on your phones memory card. Then on the phone set your wallpaper from the gallery and select the black image.

Comment: That's what I did. I created a 1x1 png file with a #000000 pixel. My Galaxy A7 2018 won't allow it. It said something like image too small. This is just outright silly. As somebody said, even Windows 3.1 has it.

Comment: Gimp > New > Width: 1080, Height: 1920 > Bucket Fill > Export As > solid_background.png

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to create a black image is to keep the phone with camera down on desk (so that no light falls on the camera) and shooting an image.

Then simply set the recently shot image as your wall paper. :)

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers*, and super excited to announce that we just published a new app for this!

We focused on making it simple and really good looking to change your wallpaper to a solid color of your choice within the palette of Android Lollipop material colors. You can find the app in Google Play:
[Material Colors Wallpaper HD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.appdictive.colorwallpaper.material&referrer=utm_source%3Dandroidstackexchange)

Have a nice one :)

Comment: Very nice! Would have loved to seen a black variant though. Only gray.